# Selenium python button

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, button

I'm noob with selenium, i need help to click a button between button tags. I tried to use find_element_by_tag_name, but it does not work cause there are other button tags scattered around before and if i try by_class_name or by_xpath it tells me there is nothing that can match and return a "exception". Please anyone could help me?
this is code:

```
<div class="footer--1L-3T">
 <div class="buttonContainer--33jjD" data-role="button-container">
  <div class="buttonContainerItem--286mU restrictedMinWidth--1yzrO" data-role="button-container-item">
   <button class="button--3h5xe buttonSizeDefault--3mQ1i buttonStateDefault--3rSF6 
   buttonLabelPositionInside--2JRkN buttonIconPositionLeft--2FL2w buttonThemePopup--38gEr 
   buttonModeDesktop--i3Cpv buttonFitWidth--2WSgF" data-role="button" tabindex="-1">
    <span data-role="button-bordered" class="bordered--3kSwE roundingBoth--177dl">
     <span data-role="button-label" class="label--2kPAA labelCapitalized--3pF45">Exit</span>
    </span>
   </button>
  </div>
 <div class="buttonContainerItem--286mU restrictedMinWidth--1yzrO" data-role="button-container-item">
  <button class="button--3h5xe buttonSizeDefault--3mQ1i buttonStateDefault--3rSF6 
  buttonLabelPositionInside--2JRkN buttonIconPositionLeft--2FL2w buttonThemePopup--38gEr 
  buttonModeDesktop--i3Cpv buttonFitWidth--2WSgF" data-role="button" tabindex="-1">
   <span data-role="button-bordered" class="bordered--3kSwE roundingBoth--177dl">
    <span data-role="button-label" class="label--2kPAA labelCapitalized--3pF45">OK</span>
   </span>
  </button>
 </div>
</div>
```

i have to click "ok" button which is the second.

Answer (score 0):

XPath for this situation is `/html/body/div/div/div[2]/button`. The number (`div[2]`) points to second div (in which is button).

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
driver.get("file:///Users/BelKed/Desktop/test.html")

ok = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/button")
ok.click()
```

Anyway, you could get X-Path from browser when you are in Web Inspector. For that right click on element you want and select "Copy –> XPath" or something similar.